# SqlDataSource Gridview not updating but doesnt crash either

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

```
 <label>Date</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="entry"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" CssClass="validator"
  ErrorMessage="A date is required." ControlToValidate="txtDate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="dateValidator" CssClass="validator" runat="server" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ControlToValidate="txtDate"
  ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date"></asp:CompareValidator>
<br />



<label>Description</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMealDescription" runat="server" CssClass="entry" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" CssClass="validator"
 ErrorMessage="Please describe the meal." ControlToValidate="txtMealDescription"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Meal description cannot be longer than 250 characters. Please try again."
  ControlToValidate="txtMealDescription" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" CssClass="validator"></asp:CustomValidator>
<br />




<label>Type</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMealType" runat="server" CssClass="entry" >
  <asp:ListItem Text="Breakfast" Value="Breakfast"></asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Text="Dinner" Value="Dinner"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Meal" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" CssClass="error"></asp:Label>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
  runat="server" 
  CellPadding="4"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
  DataKeyNames="MealID,Date,MealDescription,MealType"
  OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdate"
  OnRowDeleted="GridView1_RowDelete" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">

  <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />

  <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
  <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
  <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
  <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
  <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
  <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

  <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

  <Columns>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="MealID" HeaderText="ID" Visible="false" />

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGridDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date", "{0:M/dd/yyy}") %>' Width="75px"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGridDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Date", "{0:M/dd/yyy}") %>' Width="75px"></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Meal Description">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGridMealDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MealDescription") %>' Width="500px"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGridMealDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MealDescription") %>' Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Meal Type">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblGridMealType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MealType") %>' Width="100px"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGridMealType" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("MealType") %>' Width="100px">
          <asp:ListItem Text="Breakfast" Value="Breakfast"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Dinner" Value="Dinner"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>            
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="true" HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-Width="75px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');"
          CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" Width="50px"></asp:button>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

  </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
  runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CampRandolphMenuTwoConnectionString %>" 
  InsertCommand="sp_ins_MenuItems" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"
  SelectCommand="sp_sel_MenuItems" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
  UpdateCommand="sp_edit_MenuItems" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
  DeleteCommand="sp_del_MenuItems" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">
  <InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Date" DbType="Date" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="MealDescription" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="MealType" Type="String" />
  </InsertParameters>
  <UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="MealID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="date" DbType="Date" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="MealDescription" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="MealType" Type="String" />
  </UpdateParameters>
  <DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="MealID" Type="Int32" />
  </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Above is my code. Everything works minus the update section.  It doesn't crash, it doesn't do anything.  That's the issue.  The new values are note updated in the database.   The code below is the stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_edit_MenuItems]
@MealID int,
@date date,
@MealDescription varchar(250),
@MealType varchar(10)
as
begin
UPDATE Menu
SET
date = @date,
MealDescription = @MealDescription,
MealType = @MealType
WHERE 
(MealID = @MealID)
END
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you. Also, when attempting to update the required field validators for the textboxes up top kick in, which are used for the insert.  Not sure why that's happening.

Code behind:

```
public partial class EditMenuTwo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ddlMealType.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
ddlMealType.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["Date"].DefaultValue = txtDate.Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["MealDescription"].DefaultValue = txtMealDescription.Text;
SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["MealType"].DefaultValue = ddlMealType.Text;

try
{
  SqlDataSource1.Insert();
  txtDate.Text = "";
  txtMealDescription.Text = "";
  ddlMealType.Text = "";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  lblError.Text = "A database error has occcurred. <br /><br />" +
    "Message: " + ex.Message;
 }
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdate(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Exception != null)
{
  lblError.Text = "A database error has occurred.<br /><br />" +
    "Message: " + e.Exception.Message;
  e.ExceptionHandled = true;
  e.KeepInEditMode = true;
}
else if (e.AffectedRows == 0)
{
  lblError.Text = "Another user may have updated that category." +
    "<br />Please try again.";
}
}

protected void GridView1_RowDelete(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
 {
if (e.Exception != null)
{
  lblError.Text = "A database error has occurred.<br /><br />" +
    "Message: " + e.Exception.Message;
  e.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
else if (e.AffectedRows == 0)
{
  lblError.Text = "Another user may have updated that category." +
    "<br />Please try again.";
 }
 }


 protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
 {
   args.IsValid = (txtMealDescription.Text.Length <= 250);
 }

 }
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {

  DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["Menu"];


  GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["MenuId"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Date"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["MealDescription"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
  dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["MealType"] = ((DropDownList)(row.Cells[4].Controls[0])).Text;


  GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

  GridView1.DataBind();
  }
```

Now receiving the following error:

Line 93:       dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["MenuId"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text

Comment: Please post GridView1_RowUpdate, plus any other methods called during the update.

Comment: The issue is that you aren't actually doing anything when the update occurs.  All it is doing is checking to see if an error occurs.  Once you add the update commands, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of what is missing from update method:

```
protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{    
    //Retrieve the table from the session object.
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["TaskTable"];

    //Update the values.
    GridViewRow row = TaskGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Id"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Description"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["IsComplete"] = ((CheckBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Checked;

    //Reset the edit index.
    TaskGridView.EditIndex = -1;

    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
}
```